# How to make an object look like it's reflected in water in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, minimalistic, reflection

How do you make an object look like it's being reflected on a body of water using Adobe Illustrator? Something like the image below but with a minimalist aesthetic:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use the *warp tool* to smudge around vector drawings. You can also use wrinkle and scallop tool for your benefit in these cases

[image: warp tool]

**Image 1**: Warp tool can be found under the same tool button as width tool

- Step 1: Make a duplicate of the object you want to smudge mirror it upside down and scale it down a bit in one direction.

  [image]
- Step 2: Use the smudge tool to deform the image by dragging sideways and slightly up with a big brush and then progressively smaller one.

  [image]

  TIP: You can double click on the smudge tool to adjust simplification options down for more detail.
- Step 3: Overlay with strips of black.

  [image]

Tweak to your hearts content. This is just a very quick demo done in about 7 minutes (up and including finding the moon model in image collection and vectorisation). There is lot i would do better if this was for a project of mine.

Comment: @user287001 i dont think your answer is so bad, its a perfectly viable option.

Answer (score 2):

Use the available distortion effects and transparency mask

An example:

[image]

Comment: perhaps Warp tool is better suited for this workflow than a mesh