# How can I replicate this effect in Photoshop / Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'd like to know how this is done. I have both photoshop and illustrator.

[image: there you go mate]

Comment: Please embed the photo, nobody wants to click a random unknown link. Ask us exactly what you need to know and what you have tried already.

Comment: done, sorry mate.

Comment: [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87045/how-to-make-an-object-look-like-its-reflected-in-water-in-adobe-illustrator/87060#87060) is a near duplicate that explains how to do this in illustrator. In photoshop you would use liquify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an object look like it's reflected in water in Adobe Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87045/how-to-make-an-object-look-like-its-reflected-in-water-in-adobe-illustrator)

Comment: The smudge tool in photoshop will also do the same thing.

Comment: @EvanCarslake actually The smudge tool isn't equivalent. It is more like spreading the colors to the drawing direction.

Answer (score 5):

The distortion is all relatively constrained to a specific angle so you could use an envelope mesh distortion in Illustrator (not that you *are* constrained to a specific angle with a mesh but it is an easy way to do so)...

Rotate your artwork to your desired distortion angle and add a mesh envelope (*Object → Envelope Distort → Make with Mesh...*) with an appropriate number of rows and columns:

[image]

Use the Direct Selection Tool to move around anchors on the mesh:

[image]

Rotate your artwork back to it's original position:

[image]

Comment: you should increase fidelity to your distort by choosing **Object > Envelope Distort > Envelope Options...** Less polygonlike look.

Comment: @joojaa yeh I always have fidelity on 100, not sure why it's looking so messy here

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this in Photoshop

Open the image.

Go to Filter - Liquify.

A dialogue box will open.Click on advance option.

A brush tool will be visible when you take the mouse on the image. Click and drag it over the image to get the desired effect.

You can also adjust the size, density etc of the brush tool.

[image]

Comment: I agree that this is most likely the method that is used, however the example has *very* clean jags, that seem to be of almost all the same size. I think the creator first created the 'template' including jagged side pieces, and then used liquify to warp the content into them. Otherwise you could never achieve such clean precise look.

Comment: You can snap to guides... Or you can use a mesh to wrap the result @JaneDoe1337

Comment: @joojaa yes that's what I meant with template, thanks :)

Comment: how do i snap to guides? I like the clean look.

Comment: or create a mesh

Answer (score 1):

There's the Warp tool in illustrator. It resembles Photoshop's Liquify.

The Warp tool is called by pressing Shift+R. It can be found under the Width tool in the toolbox.

Doubleclicking the Warp icon opens the options dialog that have plenty of control over the results.

The texts must be outlined and raster images must be embedded (for example pasted). Normal text and linked photos do not get warped.

This is a screenshot of a warping example. The text is a random sample from Stack Exchange blog and the image is an unrelated random piece from MS Powerpoint clipart.

[image]